# How to remove md5 to php

Tags: php, md5

I need help,
remove need a php code without damaging the function md5.
I have no idea and do not want to destroy the code.

```
<title>PROXAT</title>
<?php

if(!isset($config->complete))
{
    return include $pages['setup'];
}

if(isset($_POST['cmd']))
{
    $messages = array();
    switch($_POST['cmd'])
    {
        case 'login':
            if(!$core->allset($_POST, 'user', 'pass'))
            {
                break;
            }
            if(strlen($_POST['user']) == 0)
            {
                $messages[] = 'Introduzca su nombre de usuario';
            }
            if(strlen($_POST['pass']) == 0)
            {
                $messages[] = 'Por favor, introduzca su contraseña';
            }
            if(!empty($messages)) break;

            $user = $mysql->fetch_array('select * from `users` where `username`=:a;', array('a' => $_POST['user']));
            if(empty($user) || !$mysql->validate($_POST['pass'], $user[0]['password']))
            {
                $messages[] = 'Error de usuario / clave';
                break;
            }

            $loginKey = md5(time() . json_encode($_POST));
            setCookie('loginKey', $loginKey, strtotime('+ 1 year'));
            $_COOKIE['loginKey'] = $loginKey;
            $mysql->query('update `users` set `loginKey`=:a where `username`=:b;', array('a' => $loginKey, 'b' => $user[0]['username']));
            $messages[] = 'Usted será redirigido a la pagina princial en segundos..' . $core->refreshLogin();
            $core->auth = true;
            break;
        case 'register':
            if(!$core->allset($_POST, 'user', 'pass', 'mail'))
            {
                break;
            }
            if(strlen($_POST['user']) < 5 || strlen($_POST['user']) > 32 || !ctype_alnum($_POST['user']))
            {
                $messages[] = 'Su nombre de usuario requiere 5-15 caracteres alfanuméricos (a-z/0-9)';
            }
            if(strtolower($_POST['user']) == 'unregistered')
            {
                $messages[] = 'Ese nombre de usuario es reservado.';
            }
            if(strlen($_POST['pass']) < 6)
            {
                $messages[] = 'Usted está obligado a elegir una contraseña con al menos 6 caracteres.';
            }
            if(!filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            {
                $messages[] = 'Por favor, introduce una dirección de correo electrónico válido.';
            }
            if(!empty($messages)) break;

            $count = $mysql->fetch_array('select count(*) as `count` from `users` where `username`=:a or `email`=:b or (`connectedlast`=:c and `username`!=:d);', array('a' => $_POST['user'], 'b' => $_POST['mail'], 'c' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'd' => ''));
            if($count[0]['count'] > 0)
            {
                $messages[] = 'Ya esta registrado ese nombre de usuario, o si ya tienes una cuenta, haga Login!';
                break;
            }

            /* Insert Pre-Registration-ID Here (Unregistered) */
            $vals = array(
                'id' => 'NULL',
                'username' => $_POST['user'],
                'nickname' => $_POST['user'],
                'password' => $mysql->hash($_POST['pass']),
                'avatar' => rand(0, 1759),
                'url' => '',
                'k' => rand(-1000000, 1000000),
                'k2' => rand(-1000000, 1000000),
                'k3' => rand(-1000000, 1000000),
                'xats' => $config->xats,
                'reserve' => $config->xats,
                'days' => time() + ($config->days * 86400),
                'email' => $_POST['mail'],
                'powers' => '',
                'enabled' => '1',
                'transferblock' => '',
                'connectedlast' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                'rank' => 1
            );
            $result = $mysql->insert('users', $vals);

            if(isset($_COOKIE['referral']) && is_numeric($_COOKIE['referral']))
            {
                //$mysql->query('update `users` set `credit`=`credit`+125 where `id`=:uid;', array('uid' => $_COOKIE['referral']));
            }

            $messages[] = "Se Registro con éxito, ahora puede iniciar sesión.";
            break;
        case 'update_bio':
            if($core->auth)
            {
                $mysql->query('update `users` set `desc`=:desc where `id`=' . $core->user['id'] . ';', array('desc' => $_POST['bio']));
            }
            break;

        case 'update_pawn':
            if(isset($core->auth))
            {
                if($core->user['custpawn'] != '')
                {
                    if(substr($_POST['update_pawn'], 0, 1) == '#')
                    {
                        $_POST['update_pawn'] = substr($_POST['update_pawn'], 1);
                    }

                    if(!isset($_POST['update_pawn']) || strlen($_POST['update_pawn']) != 6 || !ctype_xdigit($_POST['update_pawn']))
                    {
                        $_POST['update_pawn'] = 'off';
                    }

                    $mysql->query('update `users` set `custpawn`=:pawn where `id`=' . $core->user['id'] . ';', array('pawn' => $_POST['update_pawn']));
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    foreach($messages as $message)
    {
        print '<div class="lpt import"> ' . $message . ' </div>';
    }
}

    if(!isset($_GET['u']) && isset($core->user['username']))
    {
        $_GET['u'] = $core->user['username'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET['u']) && ctype_alnum($_GET['u']))
    {
        $user = $mysql->fetch_array('select * from `users` where `username`=:uname or `id`=:uid;', array('uname' => $_GET['u'], 'uid' => $_GET['u']));
        if(count($user) == 1)
        {
            $nickname = htmlspecialchars(substr($user[0]['nickname'], 0, strpos($user[0]['nickname'] . '##', '##')));
            $nickname = preg_replace('/\([^)]*\)+/', '', $nickname);
            $pcount   = $mysql->fetch_array('select count(*) from `userpowers` where `userid`=:userid;', array('userid' => $user[0]['id']));
            print '<div class="container" style="margin: 0.5%; padding: 0.5%;">';
            print '<div class="left">';
            print '<div class="window">';
            print '<div class="heading" style="position: inherit; height: auto;">';
            if (is_numeric($user[0]['avatar'])) {
            echo "<tr> <td><img style=\"max-width: 100%; background-color: transparent;width: 94%;border: 1px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) solid;margin-top: 10px;\" src=\"/web_gear/av/{$user[0]['avatar']}.png\" /> </td> </tr>", PHP_EOL;
            } else {
            echo '<tr> <td><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="'.$user[0]['avatar'].'" class="mini-foto" style=" background-color: transparent;width: 94%;border: 1px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) solid;margin-top: 10px;"/> </td> </tr>', PHP_EOL;
            }
            print '<style="background-color: transparent;width: 94%;border: 1px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) solid;margin-top: 10px;">' . substr($nickname, 0, 50) . ' </div><div class="content" style="top:0;padding-top:0;"><table><tbody><tr class=""> <td> ID </td> <td class="tr"> ' . $user[0]['id'] . ' </td> </tr><tr class=""> <td> Xats </td> <td class="tr"> ' . $user[0]['xats'] . ' </td> </tr><tr class=""> <td> Days </td> <td class="tr"> ' . floor($user[0]['days'] / 86400) . '  </td> </tr><tr class=""> <td> Powers </td> <td class="tr"> ' . $pcount[0]['count(*)'] . ' </td> </tr><tr class=""> <td> Credit </td> <td class="tr"> ' . $user[0]['credit'] . ' </td> </tr></tbody></table><div style="width: 100%" class="tc">';

            print '<table style="width: 99%">';
            print '</table>';
            if($core->auth && $core->user['id'] == $user[0]['id'])
            {
                print '<div style="width: 100%" class="tc"> <input type="submit" class="claimCredit" value="Claim Credit" style="padding:4%;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" class="relogin" value="Relogin" style="padding:4%;" /> </div>';
            }
                        $usuario = $mysql->fetch_array('select * from `users` where `username`=:usuario or `id`=:uid;', array('usuario' => $_GET['u'], 'uid' => $_GET['u']));
            $powers  = $mysql->fetch_Array( 'select * from `chat_powers` where `usuario`=:id;', Array('id' => $usuario[ 0 ][ 'id' ] ) );
            If ( count( $usuario ) != 0 )
            {
            print '<br>';
            print( '<div class="tc">Sus powers de grupo<br>' );
            print( 'Actualemente[Asignados] Son:<br>' );
            print '<br>';
            print( '<strong> CHAT </strong> - <strong> POWER </strong><br>' );
            Foreach ( $powers as $power )
            print( '<i><a href="/' . $power[ 'chat' ] . '">' . $power[ 'chat' ] . '</a> </i>/<i> (' . $core->getPowerName( $power[ 'power' ] ) . ') </i><br>' );
            } //count( $usuario ) != 0
            Else
            {
            print( '<br><br><div class="tc" Usted no tiene powers activados en ningun chat!<br>' );
            }
            print( '</div><br>' );

            print '</div></div></div></div>';



            print '<div class="right">';
            print '<div style="width: auto; min-width: 400px;">';
            print '<div class="tabs" style="/*background-color: #1ba1e2; */ width: 100%;">';
            print '</div>';
            print '<div class="tabs_content" style="width:auto;padding:1%;">';
            if(isset($core->user['id']) && $core->user['id'] == $user[0]['id'] && !isset($_GET['preview']))
            {
                print '<div class="tabs_content" style="width:auto;padding:1%;">';
                print '<div class="heading"> Biografía [ <a style="color:#ffffff;" href="http://' . $config->server_dm . '/profile?u=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['u']) . '&preview">VER BIOGRAFÍA</a> ]</div>';
            }
            else
            {
                print '<div class="heading"> Biografia de '.$user[0]['username'].'  </div>';
            }

            if($user[0]['desc'] == '' && (!$core->auth || $core->user['id'] != $user[0]['id']))
            {
                print '<div class="tc" style="width: 100%"> ' . $user[0]['username'] . ' no tiene una biografía. </div>';
            }
            elseif($core->auth && $core->user['id'] == $user[0]['id'] && !isset($_GET['preview']))
            {
                print '<small style="cursor:pointer" title="[br], [center], [b], [h1], [h2], [h3]"> BB CODES (hover) </small>';
                print '<form method="post">';
                print '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="update_bio" />';
                print '<textarea name="bio" style="width: 99%;resize: none" rows="15">' . htmlspecialchars($user[0]['desc']) . '</textarea>';
                print '<div style="width: 99%;text-align: center"> <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" /> </div></div>';
                print '</form>';
            }
            else
            {
                $bb = array(
                    '[br]' => '<br />',
                    "\n"   => '<br />',
                    '[center]' => '<span class="tc" style="width: 100%;display: inline-block;">',
                    '[/center]' => '</span>',
                    '[b]' => '<b>',
                    '[/b]' => '</b>',
                    '[h1]' => '<h1>',
                    '[/h1]' => '</h1>',
                    '[h2]' => '<h2>',
                    '[/h2]' => '</h2>',
                    '[h3]' => '<h3>',
                    '[/h3]' => '</h3>',
                    '[center]' => '<center>',
                    '[/center]' => '</center>',
                );

                print str_replace(array_keys($bb), $bb, htmlspecialchars($user[0]['desc']));
            }
            print '</div></div>';
        }
        else
        {
            print '<div class="lpi import"> Usuario no encontrado :/ </div>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print '
        <div class="container">
            <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                <div class="halfopage" style="float: left;">
                    <div class="window">
                        <div class="heading"> Ingrese a su cuenta </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <table>
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="login" />
                        <tr> <td class="tl"> Usuario </td> <td> <input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="user" /> </td> </tr>
                        <tr> <td class="tl"> Clave </td> <td> <input style="width: 100%" type="password" name="pass" /> </td> </tr>
                        <tr> <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" value="Login" class="fr" /> </td> </tr>
                    </form>
                       </tbody>
                    </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div style="width: 10%; display: inline-block;"> <!-- Spacer --> </div>

                <div class="halfopage" style="float: right;">
                    <div class="window">
                        <div class="heading"> Registrar una cuenta</div>
                        <div class="content">
                    <form method="post">
                    <table>
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="register" />
                        <tr> <td class="tl"> Usuario </td> <td> <input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="user" /> </td> </tr>
                        <tr> <td class="tl"> Clave </td> <td> <input style="width: 100%" type="password" name="pass" /> </td> </tr>
                        <tr> <td class="tl"> Correo </td> <td> <input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="mail" /> </td> </tr>
                        <tr> <td colspan="2"> <label for="verificacion" class="verif">¡Si ves esto, no llenes el siguiente campo!</label>
     <input name="verificacion" class="verif" /> </td> </tr>
                        <tr> <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" value="Register" class="fr" /> </td> </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>';
    }
if (isset($_POST['verificacion']) != ""){
    // Es un SPAMbot
    exit();
}else{
    // Es un usuario real, proceder a enviar el formulario.
}
?>
<STYLE type=text/css>
body {
BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(<?php print $user[0]['xatspaceBG']; ?>)}
a{
color: #3498DB;
} --para los enlaces
a:hover{
color: #FC0404;
} --para cuando pasas sobre un enlace
a:active{
color: #04FC67;
} --para cuando lo pulsas
a:visited{
color: #0467FC;
} --para los que ya as visitado
.verif{ display: none; }
</style>
```

Comment: What are you asking?  What is the problem?  What does "remove need a php code" mean?  **What have you tried so far?**

Comment: remove the code php md5

Comment: Sorry, i use translate. I no speak english... I need remove MD5 because i no need this fuction

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you want, but this should do what I think you are asking.

Replace these lines:

```
$loginKey = md5(time() . json_encode($_POST));
```

and

```
'password' => $mysql->hash($_POST['pass']),
```

With this:

```
$loginKey = time() . json_encode($_POST);
```

and this

```
'password' => $_POST['pass'],
```

Don't forget to delete any accounts that are already registered.

Comment: I can only help you so much when you give **very little information**.  What errors do you get?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I need you to register and do not use md5 to log on does not use md5 but removing that does not work

Comment: If you have a different problem, ask a new question.  Please read the How to ask a question guide before doing so.

Comment: continues to take md5 login

Comment: So the above didn't remove md5 from your code?  Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Exactly, continues to take md5.

Comment: registered without md5, sign in with md5

Comment: It is the only code that takes registry and startup

Comment: Is it the mysql->validate?

Comment: I did not understand the question

Comment: I'm sorry its too difficult to help you when you don't speak English.  Good luck.